# ListView position changes after filtered

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, position, filtering

I'm working on a ListView:

```
    val animals = arrayOf("cat","dog", "mouse", "parrot", "lion", "panda")
internal lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

    val list = findViewById(R.id.lista) as ListView
adapter = ArrayAdapter(
this@MainActivity,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
animals)
list.adapter = adapter
```

This is the conditional for selected position item:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
        when(i) {
            0 -> {
                webView1.loadUrl("catweb1")
                phone.text = "catnumber"
                webView2.loadUrl("catweb2")
            }

            1 -> {
                webView1.loadUrl("dogweb1")
                phone.text = "dognumber"
                webView2.loadUrl("dogweb2")
            }

            2 -> {
                webView1.loadUrl("mouseweb1")
                phone.text = "mousenumber"
                webView2.loadUrl("mouseweb2")
            }

            3 -> {
                webView1.loadUrl("parroteweb1")
                phone.text = "parrotnumber"
                webView2.loadUrl("parrotweb2")
            }

            4 -> {
                webView1.loadUrl("lionweb1")
                phone.text = "lionumber"
                webView2.loadUrl("lionweb2")
            }

            5 -> {
                webView1.loadUrl("pandaweb1")
                phone.text = "pandanumber"
                webView2.loadUrl("pandaweb2")
            }
        }
```

I'm using these 3 buttons to get those selected Items do their job, since webView1 is located inside website1 layout and webView2 is located inside the website2 layout.

```
        web1.setOnClickListener {
            ListView.visibility= View.GONE
            website1.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        }
        web2.setOnClickListener {
            ListView.visibility= View.GONE
            website2.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        }
        phone.setOnClickListener {
            makeCall(phone.text.toString())

        }
```

I'm using a MenuSearch to search among the list:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android2:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android2:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android2:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass = "android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

This is the code:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)
    val item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch)
    val searchView = item.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)

            return false
        }
    })

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Everything is working fine when the list is not filtered, but my problem starts after I use the filter, if I filter for Panda, it will always load the catweb1 when clicking in web1 button, instead of pandaweb1, it will call the catnumber when clicking phone button, and load the catweb2 when clicking the web2 button.

I already looked in here for similiar questions but I only found answwers for ery complex (at least for me) CustomedAdapters for listviews.

Is there an easy way to keep the position of my items after they are filtered?

Or should I use some sort of Ifs statements instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filtering, your list has only 1 or 2 items, so the i variable can never be > 2. To fix this you need the index of the animals array.

Change your when statement to:

`when(animals.indexOfFirst { it == adapter.getItem(i) })`

Comment: Worked !! this fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need create an another list to store all inital values as follow

```
val listToFilter = mutablelistOf<...>()
listToFilter.addAll(yourList) //storing all values
```

Then

```
yourList.clean() //first, clear your list
yourList.addAll(listToFilter.filter {...}) //filtering on all values and giving them to your list
//notify your adapter about the changes
```

Comment: Thanks Abner, but I just cant make it work, can you please point me to where I should add the code? im receiving a missmatch type in:   listToFilter.addAll(list)  and unresolved reference in  .clean and in addAll.